# Multiple URL on same IP

Tags: http, redirect, https

We have added one entry in the DNS as "abc.domain.net" , When I type https://abc.domain.net its redirecting to abc login page however if I type "abc.domain.net" without https: its getting redirected to domain login page , Below are the DNS entries ,  all are pointing to same IP , please let me know if anyone has a resolutoin

www.domain.net
@(none)
abc.doamin.net

Comment: What is your exact problem? What do you expect to happen?
Sounds more like a misconfiguration of your web server, though.

Comment: Which web server are you using?

Comment: Are wanting it not to take you to the logon page if no https is typed?

Answer (score 3):

DNS isn't the issue here; if you want HTTP requests to be automatically redirected to HTTPS, this has to be configured on your web server (or your reverse proxy, if you're using one).

Answer (score 0):

You have enabled the automatic redirection from `http://windstream.workterra.net` to `https://www.workterra.net/` on your MS ISA httpd server. Specify correct redirection url to fix this problem.